# Modify a grep search when using file as source

Tags: bash, grep

Trying to output the 20 characters before the string using grep when source for queries is a file

Background on the problem: My file contains many long lines of text and I am trying to search that file for a string and output the 20 characters before the string of interest. To do so I am using the following parameters `grep -E -o ".{0,20}string"`, which works and gives the correct output when I try any given string.

The problem I am facing now is trying to combine this with the `-f` option in grep since I have many queries that are contained in a different file.

I can't find the correct way to add the .{0,20} modifier to each query contained in my text file. Any help would be great.

Comment: What about using the filtered output like so ? `grep -E -o ".{0,20}string" inputfile | grep -E -f patternfile`. If your input file is very big, it will slow the execution of your search down as you execute grep twice

Comment: To clarify is inputfile the large file I am trying to search? Not sure I understand what filtered output means in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input example (input.txt) :

```
ezfnzjnefnzefnz
ezenfjznefnkz123hello
enzjfzeknzkabcworld
fzebkfzbejkfbzk
```

Pattern file example (pattern.txt) :

```
hello
world
```

Command :

```
grep -Eo -f <(sed 's/^/.{0,3}/' pattern.txt) input.txt
```

Output :

```
123hello
abcworld
```

Sed command just adds `.{0,3}` at the beginning of each pattern. Of course you can use other methods to update the pattern file.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following, tested with shown samples only.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} {for(i in a){if(index($0,i)){val=index($0,i);print substr($0,val-3)}}}'  pattern.txt input.txt
```

Adding a non-one liner form of above solution now.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$0]
  next
}
{
  for(i in a){
     if(index($0,i)){
       val=index($0,i)
       print substr($0,val-3)
     }
  }
}
'  pattern.txt input.txt
```

Comment: You could update a bit to simplify the code, compute only once the index and be [DRY instead of WET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) : `awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} {for(i in a){if(val=index($0,i)){print substr($0,val-3)}}}'  pattern.txt input.txt`